# Allowing spaces in text input

Tags: php, html

I've created a PHP blog system. Here's what the 'create a post feature' looks like

[image]

Here's the code for it:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db_connect.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
header('Location: login.php');
exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$title = $db->real_escape_string($title);
$body = $db->real_escape_string($body);
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$body = htmlentities($body);
if($title && $body && $category){
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, title, body, category_id, posted) VALUES('$user_id', '$title', '$body', '$category', '$date')");
if($query){
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">Post Added</div>';
}else{
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">An unexpected error has occured.</div>';
}
}else{
echo '<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 40px; left: 500px; padding: 10px; background: red; box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; color: #fff;">Please enter all the required information to proceed</div>';
}
}
?>


<div id="mainbox">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Post Title Here">
<p></p>
<textarea name="body" cols=50 rows=10 placeholder="Enter Post Content Here"></textarea>
<p></p>
<select name="category">
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
echo "<option value='".$row->category_id."'>".$row->category."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

When I click submit hover and the post is created, it turns out like this: 
[image]

As you can see, the paragraphs I added in have been removed. How do I prevent this and keep the paragraphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the data is entered is with new line characters. When this is pasted in an HTML page though, they are not visible because whitespace is collapsed in HTML. To keep the line breaks, convert them to HTML with [`nl2br()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Note that it is better to convert the data each time you print it out, not store it in the database with `<br>` tags. Otherwise if you go to edit the post, suddenly you're dealing with HTML and not plain text - not something users expect. Not only that, but you would be exposing yourself to security risks by allowing arbitrary HTML.

---

So on that example page, do something like this:

```
<?php
while($query->fetch()):
$html_body = nl2br($body);
$lastspace = strrpos($html_body, ' ');
?>
<h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
<p><?php echo substr($html_body, 0, $lastspace)."<a href='blog/post.php?id=$post_id'>..</a>"?></p>
<p>Category: <?php echo $category?>
<hr />
<p></p>
<?php endwhile?>
```

Comment: Right. So I enter nl2br() between the paragraphs when I create the post?

Comment: No, you just pass the post data as a single string to `nl2br()` before printing, eg: `<?php echo nl2br($post_body); ?>`. Don't do anything when creating the post.

Comment: Add the code for the page that displays the final post, I'll tell you how to modify it.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Would it be possible for you to do it with the other code I've added to my original post please?

Comment: `echo "<p>".$row->body."</p>";` to `echo "<p>".nl2br($row->body)."</p>";` Simple really.

Comment: This is a bit off the original question, but is it possible to add a wysiwyg text editor to the create a post form?

Answer (score 0):

use **htmlentities** in php 
or html pre  **tab**

updated

```
echo "<pre>" . $postedData . "</pre>";
```

or

```
echo htmlentities($postedData);
```

Comment: after post you display the text as plain html use a <pre>your submitted data</pre> and see the result

Comment: I've tried, but to no avail. Could you post an example with my code please?